# save pdo execution results into an array?

Tags: php, arrays, pdo, prepared-statement

I am using the following to update a table in my db with various values (I have shortened this example to two).  Given an array of users ($user_set) I check to see if settings for the user exist... if they do I update the users row... if they do not then I create a row for the user.

The code below works fine, however, I need to return an array of the rows I just changed so I can update the page display with js.

Essentially what I want to do is `$result_array[] = $stmt->execute($binding);` (all values of the row updated/inserted)

This way I could `echo json_encode($result_array);` and have an array of all rows I just updated/inserted for use with js.

Is something like this possible or will I need to create the array on my own in php to return?

```
<?php

        //set bindings
        $binding = array(
            'one' => $settings['one'],
            'two' => $settings['two'],
            'user_id' => $user['user_id']
            );

        foreach($user_set as $key)
        {

            // check if program settings exist or not
            $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM settings WHERE user_id = ?");
            $stmt->execute(array($key['user_id']));

            // program_settings result is
            $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            // if result then settings exist and update... if not insert one
            if($result)
            {
                //prepare update statement
                $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE settings SET one = :one, two = :two WHERE user_id = :user_id");
            }
            else
            {
                //prepare insert statement
                $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO settings (user_id, one, two) VALUES (:user_id, :one, :two)");
            }

            //set comp id
            $binding['user_id'] = $key['user_id'];

            // execute the update
            $stmt->execute($binding);
        }

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you use a stmt->execute(); to execute some sql, you can use stmt->fetchAll(); to take all of the rows that has been affected by your sql statement.